# Wu's anti-aliasing algorithm, non black lines

Tags: java, colors, antialiasing

I've been working with [Xiaolin Wu's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm) anti-aliasing algorithm. However, I ran into a snag with the brightness adjustment. I was able to get it to work just fine with a black background. Now I've been working on color blending between the pixel I'm drawing onto and the pixel I'm drawing. (mixing the two colors based on a 0 - 1 float). I've ran into a problem with it blending with its self giving a high brightness. Any insight on how to handle this?

I can post code if needed.

Edit: this occurs at line joining (drawing lines that connect).

Comment: Check out http://www.crbond.com/papers/anti_alias.pdf - it describes a method for achieving high brightness, though I haven't tried it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

Wu draws the starting / ending points separately from the line itself, so you should be able to only draw the very last ending point of your interconnecting lines.